# XHTML page not recognizing @Controller or @Component in controller

Tags: spring, jsf, xhtml, el

I am looking at Java / JSF / Spring and am encountering a problem, when trying to fetch the information in a Bean with @Contoller or @Component the information does not go to my XHTML page the information only goes when I use @ManagedBean to define my controller.

Comment: Post your JSF/Spring integration configuration, maybe you skipped something.

Comment: EL does not know anything about the existence of Spring annotated beans unless you configure it to. Search for 'Spring EL resolver' and you'll most likely find a duplicate of your question with an answer.